# Updating redis DB efficiently while running

Tags: database, dictionary, redis

I have a big instance of redis DB, that serves multiple consumers. While it's running, I need occasionally to update it, with a new dictionary of key-values. Some of the keys exist, and some are new. After the update, the redis database needs to be identical to the dictionary. I can't delete all keys, because the consumers need to query it while updating.

Is there a generally good method to do such an update? I can for example keep in memory all the keys of both dictionaries and delete keys that don't exist in the new dictionary, but the redis is too big to save all keys in memory.